# Able to set width % but not height

Tags: css

I'm a beginner in css, and I have tried to find the answer but I couldn't find it. So please bear with me :D

I have a meta in my code (because it's a responsive mobile web), i will show it in case its related to my problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
   initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

This is a part of my code, where I want to change the `img` `width` and `height` with css :

```
<div id="desc">
    <img alt="" src="images/MallDetail/MallDesc.png">
</div>
```

So I tried something like this:

```
#desc img {
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%; 
}
```

Then a weird thing happened: the width is working perfectly, the `img` `width` size is 95% of the current width, but the `height` is not working - it's just not changing (its `height` should be 50% of the current height).

I also have `margin 0` and `padding 0` to reset my css.

Why is this happening? What should I do to get things working?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks for your help :D

Comment: height/width percentages are of containing block height/width not original height/width

Comment: Have you tried giving `#desc` a definite width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set height using %. The height automatically increases when width increases when using % for width.

you should use min-height: 90px; then height increases based on content inside.

e.g.

```
    <div id="mainContainer">

       <img src="HelloWorld" alt="" style="width:100%" />
       <div class"newContent">
       <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainContainer{
  min-height: 80px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I want to ask, so do i need to provide a bigger image if i want to increase my img width? :D

Comment: i think you should keep a larger image incase someone views on large screen, then the resolution will remain intact.

Answer (score 1):

If width is working correctly, then img only needs the `height:auto;` And I like to let my imgs fill their parents when building fluid sites, so set the other `width` and `margin` on `desc`. This will work fine if the image is square and you want to maintain the height/width ratio.

```
#desc {
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0 2.5%; 
}
#desc img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

If this isn't the goal, the best way to adjust height is using javascript. I usually apply a ratio to the width to get the height.

jquery

```
var descImg = $('#desc img')
descImg.height( descImg.width() * 0.5 + 'px' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I want to ask, so do i need to provide a bigger image if i want to increase my img width? :D

Comment: That depends how it looks when the image stretches.